# Low-dimensional data and quantum machine learning

Tags: speedup, machine-learning

Ewin Tang says to not expect exponential speed-ups from quantum machine learning using **low-dimensional data** because, in such cases, quantum analogues of classical algorithms will *not* provide outperformance.

What then is the definition of low-dimensional data exactly in classical machine learning for an array with $N$ rows and $K$ columns? Can such an array even be considered high-dimensional, and if so, in which direction ($N\gg K$ or $K\gg N$)? Or does high-dimensionality require that the array possess a third dimension ($N$, $K$ *and* $M$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Context

The algorithm Ewin Tang originally [examined and dequantized](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.04271) was the [quantum recommendation system algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08675) by Kerenidis & Prakash.

Many QML algorithms, including the quantum recommendation system algorithm, exploit the quantum linear systems algorithm (QLSA), which was [posted on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) in 2008 by Harrow, Hassidim, and Lloyd (that's why it's also sometimes known as the HHL algorithm). The QLSA algorithm solves a quantum linear system of equations (i.e. the input is quantum information) via matrix inversion. Formally, given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and a vector $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, the task is to solve for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ in the system $\mathbf{A} \vec{x}=\vec{b}$. Note that the original QLSA didn't include a data loading or measurement procedure (important when considering its complexity).

### About Speed

The QLSA outputs a solution with complexity $O(d^4\kappa^2\log N/\epsilon)$, where $d$ is the density of $\mathbf{A}$, $\kappa$ is the magnitude of the ratio of the largest to smallest eigenvalues of the matrix (i.e. $\kappa = \vert\lambda_{\max}/\lambda_{\min}\vert$), and $\epsilon$ is the precision.

Focusing on $d$ and $\kappa$, we can define them in layman's terms as:

- $d$ is the maximum number of non-zero entries among the rows of $\mathbf{A}$
- $\kappa$ is the magnitude of the ratio between the largest and smallest eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$

Over the years, several improvements have been made to the QLSA – so this complexity can be considered higher than what is theoretically possible.

### And on Dimensionality...

First off, we typically talk about the dimensionality of a data matrix in terms of its columns – that is, an $m\times n$ matrix would be high dimensional $n \gg m$, where $m$ is the number of rows (samples) and $n$ is the number of columns (features). You could think of this in the context of the QLSA where $\mathbf{A}$ is the data matrix for a linear regression.

I'd argue that Tang is making a general statement about algorithmic complexity. Specifically, that you need a large input (matrix) to get a meaningful speedup up, just given the complexity of the algorithm and a comparable classical approach like Gaussian elimination (which is $O(N^3)$) or one of Tang's dequantized (classical) algorithms, which (as I understand them) end up having polynomial complexity, though the polynomials are of quite high order(s) on some term(s).

That said, another point is that given the polynomial terms $d$ and $\kappa$ and the $\log N / \epsilon$, if $N$ is relatively small and $d$ and $\kappa$ are large, the latter are going to have a greater influence on the complexity.

Comment: if a high-dimensional matrix has $n$ columns $\gg m$ rows, is it still high-dimensional if you transpose it, causing $n \ll m$?

Comment: Yes, in the data model, we think of features as dimensions of the data; even if you transpose it the features are still the features.